# Convolution inequality

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $u$ and $v$ be two $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions such that 
$\|u\|_{L^1} \le \|v\|_{L^1}$ and $f$ is non-negative $L^1(\mathbb{R})$
with non-negative inverse Fourier transform.
Is it true that for the convolution
$\|u*f\| \le \|v*f\|$?
If not, maybe someone know additional condition that
will give the last inequality.

Comment: In what norm is the desired inequality?

Answer (score 1):

If you additionally assume that the functions are in $L^2$ you could use Plancherel to obtain $\|u \ast v\|_2 = \|\hat{u} \hat{f}\|_2$. So now $\hat{f} \geq 0$ so the multiplication operator is order preserving.

I assume you mean the $L^2$ norm in your desired inequality (natural for convolutions).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the $L^1$ norm of the convolution. The desired inequality is $\|u*f\|_1 \le \|v*f\|_1$. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Just one little detail, why is $\hat{f}\geq0$?

Comment: Also, as I see it $L^1$ is more natural since it is closed under convolution.